# A question dealing with finite unions and type.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I've been independently reading Kunen's newest set theory book for a self-study course. I'm looking at his chapter on cardinal arithmetic, thoroughly reading proofs and working on exercises. After an exercise of the Milner-Rado Paradox, he mentions that types are bounded when it comes to finite unions and states the following exercise:

> Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal and $\alpha = \bigcup_{n<c}X_n$, where $c < w$ and type$(X_n) < \kappa^{\omega}$, then $\alpha < \kappa^{\omega}$.

Intuitively, it seems to make sense, but I'm having trouble coming up with a formal proof. Would I use induction on $n$? Any help or hints would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that if $\operatorname{type}(X_i)<\kappa^\omega$ for $i=1,2$, then $\operatorname{type}(X_1\cup X_2)<\kappa^\omega.$

Visualize $X_1$ as an ordinal $\alpha<\kappa^\omega$. When you add $X_2$ to $X_1$, for each $\beta<\alpha$ you're adding between $\beta$ and $\beta+1$ a set of type at most $\operatorname{type}(X_2)$, and as you're doing this $\operatorname{type}(X_1)$ times, you get that $\operatorname{type}(X_1\cup X_2)\leq\operatorname{type}(X_2)\cdot\operatorname{type}(X_1)<\kappa^\omega.$

Comment: You may enjoy reading the beginning of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/440200/462), where I mention a result of Toulmin characterizing precisely what the possible values of $\mathrm{type}(X_1\cup X_2)$ can be in terms of $\mathrm{type}(X_1)$ and $\mathrm{type}(X_2)$.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: Your reasoning makes sense. Once we know that the type of $X_1 \cup X_2$ is less than $\kappa^{\omega}$, then does it automatically follow that $\alpha < \kappa^{\omega}$ since we just keep adjoining an extra $X_i$ to the union? For instance, type$((X_1 \cup X_2) \cup X_3)$ would be less than $\kappa^{\omega}$, and so on.

Comment: @josh yes, indeed, as type$((X_1\cup X_2)\cup X_3)\leq\operatorname{type}(X_1\cup X_2)\cdot\operatorname{type}(X_3)<\kappa^\omega,$ as we already know that $\operatorname{type}(X_1\cup X_2)<\kappa^\omega$.

Comment: @josh you also have to prove that whenever $\alpha,\beta<\kappa^\omega$, then $\alpha\cdot\beta<\kappa^\omega;$ using that $\kappa^\omega=\sup\{\kappa^n:n<\omega\}$

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: Sorry to ask again, but can you give a more formal explanation of why the type of the union ends up being less than $\kappa^{\omega}$? It made sense when I read it yesterday, but I'm having a hard time seeing it today.

Comment: @josh No problem, what is exactly the part that you don't understand?

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: Being of type $< \kappa^{\omega}$, I can picture $X_1$ as some ordinal $\alpha < \kappa^{\omega}$. I'm not sure if it's because I'm new to this topic, or if I need another explanation, but I'm not seeing the reasoning behind the second sentence (where you are explaining what happens when you add $X_2$ to $X_1$) .

Comment: @josh As you add $X_2$ to $X_1$ you're gonna add points between $\beta$ and $\beta+1$, and the order-type of this added points is at most $\operatorname{type}(X_2)$, but you're doing this $type(X_1)$ times, now you must recall the definition of product of ordinals; notice that we also are adding points before and after $X_1$, so we're actually doing this $type(X_1)+1$ times.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: Thanks for the clarification. I gave it more thought, and it now makes more sense. Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: How would you go about showing $\alpha, \beta < \kappa^{\omega}$ implies $\alpha \cdot \beta < \kappa^{\omega}$? Does it just follow directly?

Comment: $\alpha,\beta<\kappa^m$ for large enough $m$, then $\alpha\cdot\beta\leq\kappa^{2m}<\kappa^\omega$